# Run decorative function to DOM node in react after rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I am currently using [MaterializeCSS](https://next.materializecss.com/) in my project. Some component in the library requires calling some functions to decorate a node after rendering. For instance, I need to run

```
var instance = M.FormSelect.init(elem, options);
```

after the `<select>` node is rendered so it is decorated. However, how do I do that properly in react? My current hack is to do a `document.querySelector` (by assigning a unique ID to the component because react doesn't store the rendered node reference, unless... i use react-dom?), and run the initialization in `componentDidMount()`. While it works, but it just doesn't feel like the proper way of getting things done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for this, as described in the documentation. It states that refs are good for when you need to do imperative animations, which I believe suits your use case.

As the docs explain, the ref attribute takes a callback, and when used on an html element, the first arg of the callback is the underlying DOM node.

`<div ref={(node) => { /* perform imperative operations */ }}></div>`

Comment: Hmm, i quickly went through that part when i was going through the documentation when i was picking up React, thanks for the refresher.